# Sitecore upgrade v7.2 to 9

Tags: upgrade

Is there any upgrade tool or documentation available for migration of sitecore 7 to sitecore 9. The current upgrade documentation for sitecore 9 require v8 as prerequisite. Can the same be used for v7 as well?

Answer (score 6):

You can use Sitecore Migration tool 3.1

The Sitecore Express Migration Tool makes it easy for customers to help migrate Sitecore 6.6,7.2, 7.5 or 8.0 to the latest version of Sitecore Experience Platform 9.0 without the need to gradually upgrade from version to version. 
Please note that DMS data to xDB will still require the use of the conversion tools found on the Sitecore Experience Platform download pages.

The Express Migration Tool Migrates:

1. Content items and media
2. All users, roles and security permissions
3. Assists with configuration migrations Web Forms For Marketers items
   and data

You can download from this link : https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Express_Migration_Tool/31/Express_Migration_Tool_31.aspx

Comment: Thanks Vlad, apart from migration we are also moving from onpremise to azure paas, will it work in that situation as well or do i have to install sitecore 7 first on cloud and then upgrade?

Comment: you can not run sitecore 7 on cloud. You have to bring production site to your local environment and to upgrade it and then you need to deploy it on cloud

Comment: Is it possible if i deploy a fresh installation of v9 on cloud, create a package of all items from v7 and upload it on v9 instead?

Comment: nope, don't upload items from 7 to 9. Follow the documentation to not have surprises in future.